# How to make thumbnail of word file in MSWord 2013..?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ms-word, thumbnails

I want to make thumbnails of word files i knw the procedure of making thumbnail of word file in MS Word 2007 but dont found anything in MSWord 2013...
So plg Help Me.......

```
Steps To Make ThumbNail Of Word File In MSWord 2007
1.Open Word File In MS Word 2007
2.File Menu---->Prepare----->Properties---->Advanced Properties----->Summary
then you found a check box save as a thumbnail checked it and then save your file is saved 
but i dont find any option in MSWord 2013
```

Comment: I think this answer on Superuser for Word 2010 is the same for Word 2013. - http://superuser.com/questions/322373/how-can-i-save-a-word-2010-document-so-it-has-a-thumbnail-preview-image-in-its-m

Comment: no it is same as word 2007 i dnt found this things in 2013

Comment: This question should have been asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Attempted to flag this for SuperUser, but due to the bounty, it can't be migrated. @Coderz I would suggest you close this question and reask it on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/), where you might receive better answers from a user base more suited to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Thumbnail option is available in File Save As dialog box for Word 2103.
Also when you use export options you will see thumbnail check box.

You can see the save as in this [video](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/video-save-publish-and-share-VA104054060.aspx?CTT=1) see the "Save Thumbnail" checkbox

How to export document is [explained here](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/word2013/6.3) , there also you will find thumbnail option

Answer (score 0):

I dont have 2013 and so I am not able to test it. Please see if this helps you out. It is in MS Word 2010, but not sure if it resembles 2013.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/7425/word-2010-save-documents-to-display-with-thumbnail-picture/

Hope it works for you. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem (in Word 2013), trying to "Save Thumbnail" for a dotx (a template file). i tried several times, changing the file name each time, refreshing Win Explorer, etc.

i found that first saving it as a normal docx file *first* generated the thumbnail just fine, and then saving that docx as a template also generated a thumbnail. like it just needed a little kick.